# How to set file browse page to a specific type of files?

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts2

I can upload files using following simple code but I need to force users to upload specific type of files. At the moment users are able to upload any type of file and I can check the extension in back-end but I need to force them to upload only images in the first place.How should I do it in a way that it allow to browse Files(*.images) not All files ( * . * )

```
 <s:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
     <s:file name="file" label="Upload Image"/>
     ...
```

Comment: _not All files ( * . * )_ do you mean to set an abstract browser to the condition to not add this filter to the dialog?

Comment: @RomanC I mean just need it to accept images not any other types of file.

Comment: How do you want to accept them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `accept` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes) of the HTML `<input type="file" />`.

> ```
> accept
> ```
>
> If the value of the type attribute is file, this attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is
>   ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content
>   type specifiers:
>
> - A file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (E.g.: ".jpg;.png;.doc")
> - A valid MIME type with no extensions
> - audio/* representing sound files (**HTML5**)
> - video/* representing video files (**HTML5**)
> - image/* representing image files (**HTML5**)

It will work with `<s:file />` too because it allows Dynamic Attributes.

---

**EDIT**: you're right, for some reason, the extension and mime checks are failing, only the HTML5 way works: <kbd>[running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/rU8j3/)</kbd>

Then this will work (in most of browser, [check out the curent compatibility here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility)), suggesting an image to be chosen:

```
 <s:file name="file" label="Upload Image" accept="image/*" />
```

It is a non-blocking filter, however: `*.*` is still selectable from the dialog selectbox;

since this is only a client-side filtering, you *must* also check the contentType, and eventually extension, server side with Struts2 [File Upload Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html).

For example:

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
    <param name="allowedTypes">
       image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg
    </param>
    <param name="allowedExtensions">
       .png,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg
    </param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Comment: how about if I use allowedExtensions and allowedTypes parameters of the interceptor? I also added the attribute but it is still loking for all types of file. <input type="file" id="my_file" accept=".png;.jpg" value="" name="file">

Comment: at the moment I am checking the extension of files in the back-end using FilenameUtils.getExtension(fname); do you know of any better solution?

Comment: you're right, first two examples from the docs are not working. Please check out the updated answer. For the rest, of course use File Upload Interceptor, with Struts2 you've no need to use FilenameUtils or whatever, it is already inbuilt

Comment: I used the image/* and it is now looking for images, but there is a problem, it is looking for all types of images, jpe,jpg,jpeg but I need to look for specific ones, (only jpeg, png and gif)